# Knockout, ViewModel is object no computed possible?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have problem, my Knockout ViewModel is NO function and this IS NEEDED:

```
vmNeu = {
KdLand: ko.observableArray(),
SelectedKdLand: ko.observable(),


Ansprechpartner: ko.observableArray([]),
ApListe: ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var apList = [];
        $(this.Ansprechpartner()).each(function(index, ap) {
            var vollerName = ap.Vorname + ' ' + ap.Nachname;
            if (ap.IstStandard) {
                vollerName += ' (Standard)';
            }

            apList.push({ label: vollerName, value: ap.AnsprechpartnerNr });
        });
        return apList;
    }
})
```

};

Everything until now worked great, observables and subscriptions, but now I want to use an computed and I cant access an other property from my viewModel, I tried everything ;(

Is there a possibility?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on the [docs for computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), you'll see that `ko.computed` takes an argument for the scope of `this`. Try changing your code so it works like in the examples and it should work

Comment: Just to be clear, the signature for computed defined inside the object (as in this example) should be "ApListe: ko.computed(function {..}, this);"  If you are adding it outside the object definition you need to pass the object references like "vm.ApListe = ko.computed(function {..}, vm);"